# How to verify a tooltip text using mouse over in selenium?

Tags: automated-testing, selenium, selenium-webdriver, robotframework

I have a test scenario that is to verify a tooltip text on a particular element so I tried to use a Selenium inbuilt keyword "Mouse Over `<xpath>`" but this doesn't work though the test is passing.

I also used other keywords such as "Focus `<xpath>`" and "Simulate `<xpath>`  click" this also seems not working though the test is passing. I am currently testing on Firefox 3.6 browser.

Could someone help me if there is any such keyword that could hover the mouse on the html element to see the tooltip.

[image]

My HTML:

```
<div class="ng-isolate-scope" ng-show="document.showMultipleRolesTooltip > 1" items-list="document.userStudyRoles" fc-multiple-roles-rollover=""> 
  <div class="fc-multiple-roles-rollover resizeable-1">
    <div class="ng-binding ng-scope" ng-repeat="item in itemsList">  
      Microbiologist
    </div>
    <div class="ng-binding ng-scope" ng-repeat="item in itemsList"> 
      Extended Site Staff
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: can you please show us your code and HTML?

Comment: <div class="ng-isolate-scope" ng-show="document.showMultipleRolesTooltip > 1" items-list="document.userStudyRoles" fc-multiple-roles-rollover="">
<div class="fc-multiple-roles-rollover resizeable-1">
<div class="ng-binding ng-scope" ng-repeat="item in itemsList"> Microbiologist </div>
<div class="ng-binding ng-scope" ng-repeat="item in itemsList"> Extended Site Staff </div>
</div>
</div>

Comment: @YuZhang  the code i tried is  Mouse Over   //div[contains(text(),'Microbiologist')] and  Focus  //div[contains(text(),'Microbiologist')]

Comment: Have you tried using other attributes?

Comment: I didn't try other attributes

Comment: Did you try `moveToElement` from Actions? Have a look at this StackOverflow question: [How-to-perform-mouseover-function-in-selenium-webdriver-using-java.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17293914/how-to-perform-mouseover-function-in-selenium-webdriver-using-java)

Answer (score 1):

Use the Actions class to mouse-over (OpenQA.Selenium.Interactions.Actions)

At this link you will find several methods.
[Mouse hover action](http://toolsqa.com/selenium-webdriver/mouse-hover-action/)

Answer (score 0):

Without using mouse hover also, we can get those tooltip by using the below code.

```
    String tooltip1 = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//div[@class='fc-multiple-roles-rollover resizeable-1']/div[1]")).getText(); // use to get the first tooltip
    System.out.println(tooltip1);

    String tooltip2 = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//div[@class='fc-multiple-roles-rollover resizeable-1']/div[2]")).getText; // use to get 2nd tooltip
    System.out.println(tooltip2);
```